# How to project cell value in dfferent cell. Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for a way to project a cells value in a different cell.
Scenerio:

- Column A = Value
- Column B = Vlookup from A
- Column C = I would like to be ONLY the value from B not the formula.

Is it possible to do this with the Indirect function? Or do I need VBA?

Comment: You need to use VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VBA you can do this by using this simple macro (assuming the data is on Sheet1) just assign it to a button or just run it through the VBA Macro Editor

```
Sub CopyCol()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B").Copy

    Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("C").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: A modification for use when Tables are used.

Answer (score 1):

A modification for use when Tables are used.

```
Sub CopyCol()

    Range("Table8").Columns("B").Copy

    Range("Table8").Columns("C").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want in column C is the Vlookup VALUE you've gotten from Column A right?

If that's the case, you can just copy column B, paste as value only in column C.
[Home > Paste > Paste Values]

Comment: Although this would work, I am looking for an answer that would use a function or macro